# Problem initializing xTensor package

Tags: warning-messages, xact

I am using Mathematica 12.2 on Windows 10 and I am using the xTensor package for my tensor calculations.
However, since today, I cannot run the xTensor package. I get the following error. Can anybody help what is the problem and what should I do?

[image]

Comment: This appears to be something better left to the developers of xTensor & xAct. I suggest contacting them at their [google group](https://groups.google.com/g/xact) to report this & get assistance.